# Printing with fixed field widths

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

This is my code so far. It does what I want it just doesn't have a fixed widths when printing the string.

```
def PrintTuple(tuple) :
    formatted = '{}, {:<15} {:<5} {:<5} {:<5} £{:<5}'.format(tuple[4], '', tuple[3], tuple[0], tuple[2], tuple[1])
    print(formatted)
```

For example it will print :

```
Potter,                 Harry Potter 12349 Wizard £30000

Capaldi,                 Peter Capaldi 13128 Timelord £50
```

I want it to print so that they have fixed widths of :

```
15, 15, 5, 15, 7
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, sorry. Can you please explain or show me?

Answer (score 0):

You have a stray `{}` in your format specifier and your field widths are not as you say you want them. Try:

```
def PrintTuple(tup) :
    formatted = u'{:<15} {:<15} {:<5} {:<15} £{:<7}'.format(tup[4], tup[3], tup[0], tup[2], tup[1])
    print(formatted)
```

gives:

```
PrintTuple((12349, 30000, 'Wizard', 'Harry Potter', 'Potter'))
PrintTuple((13128, 50, 'Timelord', 'Peter Capaldi', 'Capaldi'))

Potter          Harry Potter    12349 Wizard          £30000  
Capaldi         Peter Capaldi   13128 Timelord        £50
```

Answer (score 0):

With this string:

```
'{}, {:<15} {:<5} {:<5} {:<5} £{:<5}'
```

You're printing 6 values, but fixed width is only provided for five of them, while the first is printed with whatever width your data has, and thus breaks formatting for the remaining values too. You need to provide width for first value for it to work:

```
'{:<15}, {:<15} {:<5} {:<5} {:<5} £{:<5}'
```

Also, if your string is longer than width qualifier, the string will not be truncated by `str.format()` method, this is something you have to do by yourself. If you don't, then fields longer than the allotted width will also break formatting. See how both "Wizard" and "Timelord" are both longer than the `{:<5}` width that you allocated for them.